# Which constructor will be executed?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

Here, a parameterised constructor is declared but the object corresponding to that constructor is not created. But the output is 10 20 which is the execution of parameterized constructor, why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class constructor
{
    int x, y; 
    public:
    constructor(int a = 10, int b = 20 )
    {
        x = a; 
        y = b;
    }
    void Display()
    {
        cout<< x << " " << y << endl;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    constructor objBix;     
    objBix.Display(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have specified default values for the arguments, so you have actually defined a custom default constructor.

Comment: unrelated, and the only real benefit for type `int` is consistency but your c tor could use an init list `constructor(int a = 10, b = 20) : x(a), y(b) { }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have defined a custom constructor with *all* default arguments, it will serve as the default constructor. The compiler won't generate another default one because that would cause ambiguity when deciding which function to call. So what's actually called is your custom constructor with all default arguments used. A compiler-generated "default" doesn'y exist at all.

Reference: [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

> A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or **with default arguments provided for every parameter**).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

> A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or with default arguments provided for every parameter).

Compiler will only implicitly generate a default constructor for you if no other constructors are provided, so in your example it is not generated.

Comment: so if I ask which constructor has been called, parametrized or default? then what will be the answer?

Comment: You have only one constructor which is both parameterized and default because it can be called with an empty parameter list due to default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You did define a no-arg constructor, overriding the default constructor. You gave default values for the parameters, and hence you can call it without arguments and your defaults are used.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the Parameterized constructor has been defined with all the parameters having some default values. So, even if you create an object without passing any arguments, it will treat the Parameterized constructor as default constructor and it gets called.
for example, if you define constructor as

```
constructor(int a, int b = 20 )
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```

Then you have to create new object of the class with at least one value which will be assigned to parameter "a".

Answer (score -1):

as you can read in previous answers, since you gave default values for the arguments this is the default constructor for this class objects.

so it's like write:

```
constructor()
{
    x = a; 
    y = b;
}
```

this is exactly what you did!

Comment: I assume you mean `constructor()` -> `constructor(int a, int b)`?